# List of names sorting them by LastName

Tags: c#, linq

I need to read a list of names in one line with `','` for example:
`John Doe, Johnny Di, ...`
I am a *beginner* so I don't really know how to properly read from a list but this is what I managed to scramble

```
var names = new List<string>();

string name1 = Console.ReadLine();

while (name1 != "")
{
    names.Add(name1);
                    
    name1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
               
var res = from name in names
          orderby name.Split(" ")[1]
          ascending
          select name;
```

Comment: `var names = Console.ReadLine().Split(',')` ?

Comment: Your code doesn't read in a comma separated list of names, it reads in names one at a time until a blank is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var res = Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
  .OrderBy(name => name
             .Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .LastOrDefault(),
           StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  .ToList(); // .ToArray(); if you want an array
```

Here we

1. Read user input - `Console.ReadLine()` - all names separated by commas (e.g. `John Doe, Johnny Di, John Smith`)
2. Split user input by `,` while trimming each item (let be nice and tolerate *spaces* before and after commas like `John Smith, Jack Doe`)
3. Order items: we `Split` `name` to get *last* name. `LastOrDefault` for the last name
4. Let's have a list (`List<string>`) as a `res`